Office Add-In issue with " namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' " and invalid child element
I face the issue, that while trying to resolve all the issues in my code for my MS Office Add-In, I get repeatedly the following error code from my terminal after calling the npm run validate function:
XML Schema Validation Error: Error found during XML Schema validation.
  - Details: The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'webApplicationInfo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. List of possible elements expected: 'FormSettings' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'.
  - Line: 30
  - Column: 4

This is line 30 of my code: <webApplicationInfo>, and those are the following ones:
<webApplicationInfo>
    <id>myIdNumber</id>
    <resource>https://graph.microsoft.com</resource>
    <applicationPermissions>user.read, tasks.readwrite</applicationPermissions>
  </webApplicationInfo>

I would appreciate if someone could explain me what the issue might be and more important how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance
I moved the <webApplicationInfo> section several times because I thought my .xml file has issues with reading it in the right order.

Well, it's not something I know anything about, but the spec at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/officeapp?view=common-js-preview says what children are allowed for the OfficeApp element and they don't include webApplicationInfo.

The error message explains everything, I believe, and is very descriptive. You have an invalid child element webApplicationInfo. You would need to refer to the documentation on the WebApplicationInfo element, here you are able to see the example of the element and correct name of the element which is WebApplicationInfo; in your case the element name starts from small letter, which is wrong and this is what validator trying to say. Please check the children elements of the WebApplicationInfo. I don't want to say anything about your typing abilities, but I would suggest using copy&paste instead. In this case, you will be able to avoid simple typing mistakes and concentrate on the manifests valid values. Please have a look at the valid children list, as there is no applicationPermissions tag. I guess you thought about Scopes and Scope elements instead. When those errors are corrected take a look on the placement of WebApplicationInfo block inside a particular version of VersionOverrides.
